# When do system variables update in IPython kernel?

Tags: python, macos, environment-variables, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I started a notebook by doing `jupyter notebook`, and then creating a new notebook.

Then, I went to the terminal, and I set the PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:<absolute path>
```

But, then when I go back to the IPython notebook, I try to print this new system variable:

```
import os
print(os.environ["PATH"].split(os.pathsep))
```

But, I don't see my `<absolute path>` that I just added??

I even tried restarting the kernel, but this doesn't help at all.  What can I do?  Thank you.

**EDIT**:

I tried to refresh my environmental variables via the terminal by doing: `bash --login`, but this did not help at all.

Also, another thing that is peculiar about this is that when I add it to the system path manually in ipython:

```
os.environ['PATH'] = os.environ['PATH'] + os.pathsep + <absolute path>
```

...it works fine in the notebook and kernel where I added it.  But, when I spin up another IPython kernel, it isn't on the PATH anymore.

I'm on `osx`.

Comment: Environment variables are inherited when a process starts. So the IPython kernel gets them from the Jupyter notebook server, which gets them from the shell where you ran `jupyter notebook`. You can't change the environment variables for another process once it has started. You can either change `os.environ` inside the IPython kernel, or stop the notebook server and launch it again from a shell where you've already made the change.

Comment: make as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
export PATH=$PATH:<absolute path>
```

in a terminal, it is only effective in this terminal session. That is to say, this `export` command has no effect on other terminal sessions.

If you want your PATH environment to be effective all the way, you need to edit your .bashrc file, and

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

to activate it.

Comment: Sorry about that. The problem may caused by server settings. Check https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/227 for any ideas?